# a loop to read lines that start with specific letters

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, readline

I'm using a for loop to read a file, but I only want to read specific lines, say line that start with "af"and "apn". Is there any built-in feature to achieve this?

How to split this line after reading it ?
How to store the elements from the split into a dictionary?
Lets say the first element of the line after the split is employee ID i store it in the   dictionary then the second element is his full name i want to store it in the dictionary too.
So when i use this line "employee_dict{employee_ID}" will i get his full name ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "built-in feature"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so very easily

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')

employee_dict = {}

for line in f:
    if line.startswith("af") or line.startswith("apn"):
        emprecords = line.split() #assuming the default separator is a space character
        #assuming that all your records follow a common format, you can then create an employee dict
    employee = {}
     #the first element after the split is employee id
    employee_id = int(emprecords[0])
    #enter name-value pairs within the employee object - for e.g. let's say the second element after the split is the emp name, the third the age
   employee['name'] = emprecords[1]
   employee['age'] = emprecords[2]
   #store this in the global employee_dict
   employee_dict[employee_id] =  employee
```

To retrieve the name of employee id 1 after having done the above use something like:

```
print employee_dict[1]['name']
```

Hope this gives you an idea on how to go about

Answer (score 0):

if your file looks like

```
af, 1, John
ggg, 2, Dave
```

you could create dict like

```
d = {z[1].strip() : z[2].strip() for z in [y for y in [x.split(',') for x in open(r"C:\Temp\test1.txt")] if y[0] in ('af', 'apn')]}
```

More readable version

```
d = {}
for l in open(r"C:\Temp\test1.txt"):
    x = l.split(',')
    if x[0] not in ('af', 'apn'): continue
    d[x[1].strip()] = x[2].strip()
```

both solutions give you `d = {'1': 'John'}` on this example. To get name from the dict, you can do `name = d['1']`

Answer (score 0):

```
prefixes = ("af", "apn")
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    employee_dict = dict((line.split()[:2]) for line in f if any(line.startswith(p) for p in prefixes))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dictOfNames={}
file = open("filename","r")
for line in file:
if line.startswith('af') or if line.startswith('apn'):
    line=line.split(',') #split using delimiter of ','
    dictOfNames[line[1]] = line[2] # take 2nd element of line as id and 3rd as name
```

The program above will read the file and store the second element as id and third as name if it starts with 'af' or 'apn'. Assuming comma is the delimiter.

now you can go with dictOfNames[id] to get the name.